# Logic gates (MOS) delay calculation

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, delay

I recently started a course in applied electronics at my university and the teacher assigned us this problem:

Calculate maximum and minimum delays (tDLH max, min and tDHL max, min) in the connection of two gates with the following electrical parameters:

$$
V_{OL}=0.4V \space V_{OH}=3V \space V_{IL}=1V \space V_{IH}=2V \space C_i=50pF \space R_{OH,OL}=130 \Omega \space R_I=1M \Omega
$$

I understood, from the theory that I have to consider the charging time of the capacitor of the MOS but after that I don't know how to continue and how to find the four times.

I used the two, charging and discharging, capacitor's formulas but I get only two times instead of four

Comment: Maybe this helps: Vil and Vih are limits below/above which behavior is defined. If the input voltage is between those the output switches "at some point".

Comment: And that's what I did. I took the capacitor charging formula and find at which time it was equal to Vih, and similar for the Vil part. An these are the two times that I found

Comment: Thus you now have two times for a rising signal (charging).